# Sql Multiple Update Query making faster

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have A query Like this.

```
UPDATE package
            SET DonePackageID = :NewDonePackageID ,UserId=:NewUserID
            where DonePackageID=:DonePackageID AND UserId=:UserID AND ConsumerID=:ConsumerID
```

I runned this code but just ConsumerID is changing.
I write code like this

```
    for(i){
//Query dataBase
   " UPDATE package
            SET DonePackageID = :NewDonePackageID ,UserId=:NewUserID
            where DonePackageID=:DonePackageID AND UserId=:UserID AND ConsumerID=".ID[i]
    }
```

I Have 600.000 Data and when i runned this code my MYSQL server is runned about 2 Hours. 
How can i write better than query about my issue ? How can i running faster this query ?

Comment: If you prepared the query then it should be faster than a normal query for so many request. By looking at your tags you use `PDO` but `mysqli` is about 6% faster.

Comment: use parameterized query inside a transaction. Also check `ConsumerID IN ( .... )`

Comment: I removed the SQL Server and T-SQL tags because the question explicitly mentions MySQL.

Comment: UPDATE package
            SET DonePackageID = :NewDonePackageID ,UserId=:NewUserID
            where DonePackageID=:DonePackageID AND UserId=:UserID AND ConsumerID IN (:Consumers) 

Like this ? @bansi

Comment: @MuhammedAlmaz . . . You should edit the question and explain where the list of 600,000 customers is coming from.

Comment: Its coming from my database @GordonLinoff

Comment: `ConsumerID IN (id1,id2,id3,)` but it will be easier to suggest better solution if we know where the data is from

Comment: try `ConsumerID IN (SELECT Consumers FROM table WHERE condition) `

Comment: Show more code to explain exactly what is going on in your script. Otherwise all you will get from people are **guesses**

Comment: This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery i get this error @bansi

Comment: What version of MariaDB are you using?

Comment: 10.1.13 @RiggsFolly

Comment: if there a composite INDEX with the fields DonePackage ID, UserId and ConsumerID ?

Comment: Just consumerId is changing. DonePackageId UserID is same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not want to loop through 600,000 rows and do a zillion updates.  You want to do them all in one statement.  Something like:

```
UPDATE package p JOIN
       t
       ON t.DonePackageID = p.DonePackageID and
          t.userId = p.userId
    SET p.DonePackageID = t.NewDonePackageID,
        p.UserId = t.NewUserID;
```

This assumes the correct columns in `t` (should be obvious).

This will work best with an index on `package(UserId, DonePackageId)`, even though this will slow the query down.

Updating 600,000 rows (particularly with an update on the active index) can still be slow.  You might want to do the updates in batches.  One simple method is:

```
UPDATE package p JOIN
       t
       ON t.DonePackageID = p.DonePackageID and
          t.userId = p.userId
    SET p.DonePackageID = t.NewDonePackageID,
        p.UserId = t.NewUserID
    WHERE p.DonePackageID <> t.NewDonePackageID OR
          p.UserId <> t.NewUserID
    LIMIT 1000;
```

You can just run this until no more rows are updated.

Comment: Thank you its fine to me :)